# Remove bullet points and extra whitespace

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a junior developer, trying to program a website using bootstrap and ASPx which are both new to me.

I have uploaded my code here

http://www.bootply.com/6rQLih6iXa

I want to be able to get rid of the white space on the left hand side of the collapsible menu, also I would like the menu to take up 100% of the users screen.

Can anyone help?

Comment: do you want to remove the left-side white space?

Comment: yes if possible, I also would like that when you click the toggle button so that the collapse menu items take up 100% of the phones screen width ways.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the summarized, compress, but still meaningful version of your HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1st problem

You need to set

```
list-style: none;
```

on `<ul class="dropdown menu dropdown-menu-right">` to resolve this problem:

> there is also still bullet points that shouldn't be there

## 2nd problem

The second problem as stated

> I want to be able to get rid of the white space on the left hand side of the collapsible menu

is because of this

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Resi-Tek v3</a>
```

having this style:

```
padding: 5px 75px;
```

You may remove that `<a>` to get rid of the extra space.

## UPDATE

You need to set

```
padding-left: 0;
```

on `<ul class="dropdown menu dropdown-menu-right">` to resolve this problem

Comment: ok I have applied this to the classes and it has got rid of the bullet points so thank you for that. but Ideally I would like the white space gone and the collapsible menu's to take up 100% of the screen if possible? I have updated it here http://www.bootply.com/6rQLih6iXa

Comment: Hi Trix,

I did try just flat out deleting <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Resi-Tek v3</a> just to see what would happen, and yes the menu's took up 100% of the screen which is perfect but there was still the white space on the left. I have updated it for you to see http://www.bootply.com/6rQLih6iXa

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this matter, all the problems I have had are now solved thanks to you. Have a good rest of your day.